# Uploading laravel project in cpanel

Tags: laravel, hosting, cpanel, web-hosting

I am trying to upload my Laravel project onto my web server but not work correctly.

my structure is

```
public_html/shanto_test/

app
bootstrap
public
vendor
artisan
composer.json
server.php
```

when I type in browser www.myweb.com/shanto_test

then nothing show.

Comment: Does your laravel log contain anything? `app/storage/logs`

Answer (score 0):

in that case you'd rather have to type in www.myweb.com/shanto_test/public. since the public folder would be the "document root" of your application.

reference
http://laravelbook.com/laravel-architecture/

Answer (score 0):

You can upload laravel project in cpanel following the steps below:

- In the `public_html/` folder upload the contents of the `public`
  directory of your laravel project.
- In the same dierctory level of `public_html` upload the all contents
  except that of `public` folder.

Your folder structure on cpanel will look like this:

```
public_html/
          css/
          fonts/
          js/
          ...
          index.php
app/
bootstrap/
database/
...
routes/
.env
```

Keeping this structure of folders and sub-folders in your cpanel will get your laravel project running successfully.

There are also alternative ways which involves changing folder paths but this felt the most easiest way to me.